# Where is php.ini?

Tags: windows, php

I ran phpinfo and it said it was in C:\Windows but it's not there. It's not in the php folder. I did a system search and it wasn't found.

Where is it hiding?

Comment: how you installed php ... wamp ,xamp or other ?

Comment: in wamp its in `wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9` in xamp `\xampp\php\php.ini`

Comment: On my PC it is located `C:\Program Files\PHP`. If it is not there why not use explorer to search for it (and then make a note for future reference)

Comment: you can check this by `<?php
phpinfo();`

Comment: It may be hidden for some reason. Try turning on "Show hidden files and folders" in Windows Explorer.

Comment: I just downloaded the php archive and unzipped it and linked it to apache by editing the httpd.conf file.

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby: Still don't see it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Run this code (and I am assuming your php is running, you are not able to just locate the php.ini file)

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

And check the location of the config file:

[image: Location]

Comment: This answer is lacking hand drawn objects.

Comment: @TimPost yes check the screenshot ..he is referring to the above one while php.ini location is in the circled one..let me know if im missing something :)

Comment: The Loaded Configuration file says None.

Comment: @RyanPeschel Did you try putting one in the config file path and see if it loads? You may just have a somewhat botched installation on your hands.

Comment: @RyanPeschel download a fresh one for your version and put it under that...and let me know if its working or not then

Comment: For anyone else seeing "none" there: In the default windows download, the ini files have -production or -development AFTER the .ini in the filename, which means they are not picked up.