# Running PHP in Windows: how to fix "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library" issues?

Tags: php, command-line

I have determined path to php folder and trying to run some php file and getting this message from command line.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\U1>php
Failed loading \usr\local\php5\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9.dll
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<!--error-->
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\
php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<script language=JavaScript src='/denwer/errors/phperror_js.php'></script>PHP Wa
rning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_gd2
.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<!--error-->
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_gd
2.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<script language=JavaScript src='/denwer/errors/phperror_js.php'></script>PHP Wa
rning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_mbstring.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<!--error-->
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_mb
string.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<script language=JavaScript src='/denwer/errors/phperror_js.php'></script>PHP Wa
rning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<!--error-->
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_my
sql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<script language=JavaScript src='/denwer/errors/phperror_js.php'></script>PHP Wa
rning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_mys
qli.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<!--error-->
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_my
sqli.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<script language=JavaScript src='/denwer/errors/phperror_js.php'></script>PHP Wa
rning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_pdo
_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<!--error-->
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_pd
o_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<script language=JavaScript src='/denwer/errors/phperror_js.php'></script>PHP Wa
rning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_pdo
_sqlite.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<!--error-->
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_pd
o_sqlite.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<script language=JavaScript src='/denwer/errors/phperror_js.php'></script>PHP Wa
rning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_sql
ite.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<!--error-->
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_sq
lite.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<script language=JavaScript src='/denwer/errors/phperror_js.php'></script>PHP Wa
rning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_soa
p.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<!--error-->
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_so
ap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<script language=JavaScript src='/denwer/errors/phperror_js.php'></script>PHP Wa
rning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_sql
ite3.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<!--error-->
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_sq
lite3.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<script language=JavaScript src='/denwer/errors/phperror_js.php'></script>PHP Wa
rning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\php_xsl
.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<!--error-->
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php5/ext\
php_xsl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
<script language=JavaScript src='/denwer/errors/phperror_js.php'></script>
^A
```

All libraries are open on php.ini file. I have checked them all. I am wondering why command line tries to run library in incorrect path like

```
'/usr/local/php5/ext\php_xsl.dll'
```

Does it should be like

```
'/usr/local/php5/ext/php_xsl.dll'
```

?

Comment: It's ovious that `/usr/local/php5/...`is a ...nix path and not an Window$ path. Adjust your `php.ini` settings (extensions) according to your installation. Search for the `php_xls.dll` on your disks, and you probably have the proper path for the extensions.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[Open your `php.ini` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984456/where-is-php-ini#13984489) and set the following setting to a *Windows* file path:

```
extension_dir = "X:/path/to/your/php/ext"
```

On Windows, paths that point to something on a normal hard drive have to start with a letter and then a colon, like "`C:`". Paths that *start* with a forward slash, `/`, are Unix-like paths, and will not work on Windows.

Comment: HI Thanks It helped and my script now running, but i am receiving this next msg abt dll not found: 

C:\Users\U1>php -f "z:\home\magento.dev\www\hello.php"
Failed loading \usr\local\php5\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9.dll
Hello World
C:\Users\U1>

Answer (score 4):

Adjust the following value in php.ini:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
extension_dir = "C:\path to extension directory"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also specify the extensions directory without using the full path if it's in the same folder, at least in PHP 7.2.5 (have not tested other versions).

Example:

`extension_dir = "ext"`

Where `ext` is your extensions directory.

Answer (score 2):

I have 7.4 php version. I solved this by uncommenting the following line by removing ; inside the php.ini file.

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

Note that initially, if you won't have php.ini file you should first copy and paste php.ini-development file and rename it as php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

Check the dll / library path from the error and make sure it's correct.
Updating /php.ini-> extension_dir to the correct path solves my problem.