# Location of php.ini file in Windows 8

Tags: php, ini

I am using Windows 8. I am looking for php.ini file.My phpinfo() output as like below.

[image]

My CMD ouput is as like below

[image]

I try to find php.ini file in **C:\Windows**. But could not find it. Could anyone say where can I find it ?

I read all previous questions but Could not find the file. Is there any issue to search the file as **Administrator** user of Windows ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is php.ini?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984456/where-is-php-ini)

Comment: Thanks @Moriarty for your reply. I read all those questions. But I could not find out the `php.ini` file. Could you please help me in this regard ?

Comment: Have you actually looked at what's in your screenshot (and the suggested  duplicate question) at the `D:\php7\php\php.ini`?

Comment: Thanks @Moriarty for reply. Actually that is not working `php.ini`file. If I changed there nothing happens. I am trying to configure `Xdebug`. Previously I found the `php.ini` file and I worked there. But recently I Refreshed the Windows. But now could not find the file.I am trying for a long time to find out the file.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use WampServer, so first go to it's folder, then

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.16\
```

In that folder you can find `php.ini` file

It was for `PHP 5.6`, but if you want `PHP 7.0` version's php ini file, just go one folder back and choose `PHP 7.0 folder`, here you goo. Hope it can help you )