# How to use Delete in Laravel API Route

Tags: php, json, laravel, api

I use Laravel as Backend and generate API by JSON and the i use php to get json data and delete data by route api in laravel but it's seem to be not working.
My API Route in laravel

```
Route::delete('articles/{article}', 'ArticleController@delete');
```

My Controller

```
public function delete(Article $article)
{
    $article->delete();
    return response()->json(null);
}
```

My API URL

```
http://192.168.0.21/api/articles/id
```

My PHP frontend Code for delete

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://192.168.0.21/api/articles/' . $id);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
unset($json_data['id']);
```

Any solution for these?

Comment: try to pass only id and then fetch the record and delete the record.

`public function delete($id)
{
    $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
    $article->delete();
    return response()->json(null);
}`

Comment: @Jigs1212 can you create answer?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What isn't working? Why are you returning null in json and then unset the id from it? (which doesn't exists anyway). Please provide more information

Comment: @StyleSh1t I want to delete content by id but i cannot delete it

Comment: @Jigs1212 How can i use delete route in PHP??

Comment: Show us how u r calling the ajax call or api ??

Answer (score 8):

**Route**
Pass id in the `{id}`, id of the record you want to delete.

```
Route::delete('articles/{id}', 'ArticleController@delete');
```

**ArticleController**

```
public function delete($id) {
    $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
    if($article)
       $article->delete(); 
    else
        return response()->json(error);
    return response()->json(null); 
}
```

**AJAX CALL**

```
        $.ajax({
            url: BASE_URL + '/articles/'+ id,
            type: 'DELETE',
        })
        .done(function() {
            console.log("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log("complete");
        });
```

Comment: Still can't delete it

Comment: How are u calling the route ?

Comment: $json = file_get_contents('http://192.168.0.21/api/articles/' . $id);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
unset($json_data['id']);

Comment: Like my question

Comment: Can u try using ajax jquery call or u need php only ?

Comment: What is the error ? How are u confirming whether the record is deleted or not

Comment: record delete from my database

Comment: but when i use Postman and i pass these url and method delete it's ok

Comment: i am not sure how file_get_contents work, but try the jquery ajax 
as the record is deleted try for new records

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167385/discussion-between-jigs1212-and-the-rock).

Answer (score 3):

You set the route method to DELETE but you're requesting it using file_get_contents which is GET.

You need to use curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.0.21/api/articles/' . $id);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: still can delete it

Comment: @The Rock can u please share your new code? Are there any errors?

Comment: no error but i cannot delete data that i use in my route

Comment: but when i use Postman and i pass these url and method delete it's ok

Comment: Donu have curl installed on your server.

Comment: i am not sure can u show me how can i install curl??

Comment: and curl is use for what?

Comment: What ia your operating system? Which server do u use? Anyway, if your errors are on, you should get an error about it. Make sure you set the php erros on to make sure that curl is the problem

Comment: Use this answer to find your php.ini: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13984489/3829526 and this answer to set erros on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/3829526

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add an alternative to [Jigs1212's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49442479/9039350) answer.

`Article::findOrFail($id)` requires a table type with a column that has a primary key named `id`.
So, if you have a primary key with a column name other than `id`, then you cannot use the `$article->delete();`. Because this will cause error

```
> BadMethodCallException: Method
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::delete does not exist
```

We have to change the way to find the id and delete it like [this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#deleting-models-using-queries):

**Routes**

```
Route::delete('barang_delete', [BarangController::class, 'delete']);
```

**Controller**

```
public function delete(Request $request)
{
    $kode = $request->input('kode');

    $barang = Barang::where('kode', $kode)->get();

    if (!$barang->isEmpty()) {
        Barang::where('kode', $kode)->delete();
        return ResponseFormatter::success(null, 'Barang berhasil dihapus');
    } else {
        return ResponseFormatter::error(null, 'Barang gagal dihapus', 404);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes errors occur when calling api route
then the solution by run this command:

```
 php artisan route:cache
```