# How to fix php artisan serve in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

when I run the command

```
php artisan serve
```

it's run but it show to me this error

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Doesn't seem related to Laravel or artisan, it's a php startup error so check your ini file and remove the erroneous libraries.  You should never have a .dll line for linux.

Comment: yes i think that because i use it from my php in windows -_- how can i change it ?

Comment: better install php using wamp (http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (P.S it installs apache and mysql along with php) if you are a beginner, it mostly installls all php extensions required for your laravel developlement

Answer (score 0):

This a PHP installation problem. I had this problem on my linux distro. Here's a few things you can do:

(Optional)
Uninstall PHP;
Reinstall PHP;

Edit php.ini . [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13984489/7259765) is how you find path to edit php.ini on windows.

Now check if the above lines are uncomented:
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so

If they are, its recommended to uninstall/reinstall PHP or [manually install function on windows](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php).

Remember to restart apache server after change php.ini file.