# Windows: How to install or activate SQLite3 for PHP

Tags: php, windows, sqlite

Any of the other questions are for Ubuntu only.

What I did:
In the php ini I uncommented this line: extension=sqlite3
as well as the one defining the extension_dir as ext

In PATH I added the PHP installation folder, which includes the libsqlite3.dll

"php -m" in a shell still does not show up sqlite3 (or anything similar) and any PHP file using SQLite3 results in the classic: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "SQLite3" not found in [php file]"

All the tutorials online (the two for windows that google can find) just say it's working after these steps (or even after the first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: You have the `php_sqlite3.dll`, right?**

https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.installation.php

They state:

> The SQLite3 extension is enabled by default.

and (**this is the important part**):

> Windows users must enable `php_sqlite3.dll` in order to use this extension. This DLL is included with Windows distributions of PHP.

and (you followed that already I guess)

> **Note: Additional setup on Windows as of PHP 7.4.0**
>
> In order for this extension to work, there are DLL files that must be
> available to the Windows system `PATH`. For information on how to do
> this, see the FAQ entitled "How do I add my PHP directory to the `PATH`
> on Windows". Although copying DLL files from the PHP folder into the
> Windows system directory also works (because the system directory is
> by default in the system's `PATH`), this is not recommended. *This
> extension requires the following files to be in the `PATH`*:
> `libsqlite3.dll`.

Other idea:

- Did you edit the correct php.ini? There might be several. [Where is php.ini?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984456/where-is-php-ini)

Comment: :/ This answer is exactly the point where I was at when writing the question. Still thanks for the details that the next poor guy trying to do this on windows. BUT you lead me on the right path, the "Where is php.ini" link revealed to me that simply NO .ini file is loaded at all. So no matter how many I edit it wont  matter

Comment: THANK YOU! Just for guiding me to the right path! In the Zip you download, the .ini files are actually named "php.ini development" which is of course not picked up anywhere

Answer (score 4):

**The problem is in how the default windows .ini files are named**

By default, the .ini files provided are named "php.ini-production" and "php.ini-development". Since they don't end with ".ini" they are not picked up and any edits ignored.

After renaming one to php.ini (and restarting) it finally worked.

In hindsight completely obvious but it just did not register with me for quite a while

Answer (score 0):

Open php.ini then search for "extension_dir". For windows extension_dir = "ext" and for Linux extension_dir = "./". Just simply remove ";" before extension_dir according to your OS. This extension_dir pointing to the dll's. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).